# Twice select in one query and where

Tags: mysql

I have problem with my query.

My query view like this:

```
SELECT 
            Tab1.`name`,
            Tab1.`removed`,
            Raq.`removed`,
            Raq.`type`,
            (select `value` from `raq_add` where `raq_id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id` and `key` = 'v') as `v`

FROM `reservation` `Reservation`
            left join `tab1` `Tab1` on `Tab1`.`id` = `Reservation`.`tab1_id`
            left join `raq` `Raq` on `Raq`.`id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id`
 WHERE 1
```

Okey, this query work perfectly but I need add variable to where like this:

```
WHERE `v` = 4
```

Full Code:

```
SELECT 
            Tab1.`name`,
            Tab1.`removed`,
            Raq.`removed`,
            Raq.`type`,
            (select `value` from `raq_add` where `raq_id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id` and `key` = 'v') as `v`

FROM `reservation` `Reservation`
            left join `tab1` `Tab1` on `Tab1`.`id` = `Reservation`.`tab1_id`
            left join `raq` `Raq` on `Raq`.`id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id`
 WHERE `v` = 4
```

I know I should add this variable to Select:

```
(select `value` from `raq_add` where `raq_id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id` and `key` = 'v' and `value` = 4) as `v`
```

But then the fields that `value` != 4

They displayed as null and I do not want to display them at all or show that they are different from `v` or `value` are not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the rows that match use Inner Join instead of left join

```
SELECT 
            Tab1.`name`,
            Tab1.`removed`,
            Raq.`removed`,
            Raq.`type`,
            (select `value` 
                from `raq_add` 
                where `raq_id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id` and `key` = 'v') as `v`

FROM `reservation` `Reservation`
            INNER join `tab1` `Tab1` on `Tab1`.`id` = `Reservation`.`tab1_id`
            INNER join `raq` `Raq` on `Raq`.`id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id`
 WHERE  (select `value` 
                from `raq_add` 
                where `raq_id` = `Tab1`.`raq_id` and `key` = 'v') = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the query with another select, then you'll be able to filter by it in the `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Your Query Here) t 
WHERE t.v = 4
```